# How can I merge two ".jceks" file into one?

Tags: java, security, certificate, keystore

I have two files **kestore1.jceks** and **keystore2.jceks**. 
I want to merge them and load into KeyStore object.

```java
KeyStore KEY_STORE = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");

input1 = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\tushar.moradiya\\Desktop\\keystore\\keystore1.jceks");
KEY_STORE.load(input1, Constant.JCEKS_KEYSTORE_FILE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());

input2 = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\tushar.moradiya\\Desktop\\keystore\\keystore2.jceks");
KEY_STORE.load(input2, Constant.JCEKS_KEYSTORE_FILE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
```

but it is not working. It overrides the last file in object.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read them into one object, but you can read them into two objects and then combine the contents, at least where they don't conflict:

```
    KeyStore ks1 = KeyStore.getInstance("jceks"), ks2 = KeyStore.getInstance("jceks");
    char[] pw = args[2].toCharArray(); KeyStore.PasswordProtection pp = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection (pw);
    try( InputStream is1 = new FileInputStream(args[0]) ){ ks1.load(is1,pw); }
    try( InputStream is2 = new FileInputStream(args[1]) ){ ks2.load(is2,pw); }
    for( Enumeration<String> aliases = ks2.aliases(); aliases.hasMoreElements(); ){
        String alias = aliases.nextElement();
        if( ks1.containsAlias(alias) ){ /* conflicting entry -- what to do? */ }
        ks1.setEntry(alias,  ks2.getEntry(alias, pp), pp);
        // could check type (or other details) before deciding whether to include
    }
```

---

You can also combine them into a single *file* using `keytool -importkeystore` (and them read in that single file) but that isn't a programming solution and thus offtopic, or at least borderline.

Answer (score 0):

There is other way to do this as well, using `keytool` command line utility. If this is going to be a one time thing, i recommend using the keytool. But if this is going to be your business logic, then you can do it this way:

```
    KeyStore first = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
    first.load(new FileInputStream(new File("first.jceks")), "password".toCharArray());

    KeyStore second = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
    second.load(new FileInputStream(new File("second.jceks")), "password".toCharArray());

    Enumeration<String> aliases = first.aliases();

    while (aliases.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String alias = aliases.nextElement();
        System.out.println(alias);

        KeyStore.Entry entry = null;
        try
        {
            entry = first.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("password".toCharArray()));
        }
        catch (UnsupportedOperationException e)
        {
            entry = first.getEntry(alias, null);
        }

        if (entry instanceof TrustedCertificateEntry)
        {
            second.setCertificateEntry(alias, ((TrustedCertificateEntry) entry).getTrustedCertificate());
        }
        else
        {
            second.setEntry(alias, entry, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("password".toCharArray()));
        }
    }

    second.store(new FileOutputStream(new File("second.jceks")), "password".toCharArray());
```

This copies all the first keystore entries into the second keystore.

P.S: Keep a copy of the original keystores.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this command-line tool](https://github.com/zappee/jceks-tool) to copy JCEKS keystore entries from one keystore to another.